# What is in the bonus chests you get from the Breath of the Wild DLC?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

With the Season Pass DLC for Breath of the Wild you get "3 new treasure chests" in the Great Plateau.

One includes a Nintendo Switch Promotion shirt, the other two contain "useful items". What are these useful items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content of the 3 chests :

- 1 Ruby
- 5x Bomb Arrows
- Nintendo Switch Shirt for Link to wear

That's what one player found, but as there's only the **Switch Shirt** which was announced, I think '*useful items*' in the two others chests might also mean '*random useful items*'.

[Source](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75060148)

Comment: It doesn't prove that it's not random, but that's also what I got from those three chests.

Comment: Not part of the mentioned collection, but the exclusive armor pieces found around Hyrule (from the individual DLCs) also use that same special chest type.